# Is there a way to double check delta epsilon proof?

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

I wonder if there's a way to double-check your answer in delta epsilon proofs, in other words if the chosen delta satisfy the conditions.

For example:

- Proof the limit of the following-
  $$
  \lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = 1 \quad \text{for} \quad 
  $$
  $$
  \begin{equation*}
    f(x) = \begin{cases}
          x^2 \quad x\neq1
          \\
          2  \quad x=1
             \end{cases}
   \end{equation*}
  $$

I choose delta as
$$
\delta = 1- \sqrt{1-\epsilon}
$$

Is there a way I can verify such a case?

---

edit: adding my solution:

$$
|x^2-1| < \epsilon \\
-\epsilon < x^2 -1 < \epsilon \\
\sqrt{1-\epsilon}<x< \sqrt{1+\epsilon} \\
\text{ Im looking for delta in the interval:} \quad (\sqrt{1-\epsilon},\sqrt{1+\epsilon})\\
\delta = x_0 - \sqrt{1-\epsilon}\\
\delta = 1 - \sqrt{1-\epsilon}\\
$$

Comment: The only way is to see if you can use this $\delta$ to show $|f(x) - 1|<\epsilon$.

Comment: It might help to show how you derived this particular $\delta$.

Comment: If your $\delta$ is correct then you complete the proof and show that if $0<|x-1|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-1|<\epsilon$. If you can't use this $\delta$ to complete the proof, then it is incorrect.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry for the dumb question, I'm really new to those proofs

Comment: Take an arbitrary $x\ne 1$ satisfying $|x-1|<1-\sqrt{1-\epsilon}$ and use the usual laws of algebra to try and prove that necessarily $|f(x)-1|=|x^2-1|<\epsilon$. Can this be done? If this can't be done then you made an error in your choice of $\delta$. (It's not a dumb question, these proofs are hard the first time you see them.)

Comment: I try to apply that to other question that I know that my answer is correct there (there's an answer in the book).
$$
\lim_{x \to -2} x^2 = 4 \quad \text{epsilon is given:  } \epsilon = 0.5
$$
So delta is $$\delta = \sqrt{4.5}-2  $$
from the inequation $$|x-2|<\sqrt{4.5}-2 $$ i get $$x=\sqrt{4.5}$$
but it does not satisfy 
$$
|x^2-4|<0.5\\
0.5<0.5 
$$
Did I get it wrong?

Comment: You should have $|x-(-2)|=|x+2|$. Also, even if it were $|x-2|$, I don't see how you concluded that $x=\sqrt{4.5}$. (Also, why do you assume $\epsilon=0.5$? Just as an example? Because in general you're supposed to take arbitrary $\epsilon$)

Comment: The \epsilon = 0.5 is because it's a given in the question. Shouldn't I set \epsilon = 5 ? 
x= \sqrt{4.5} is wrong, I miscalculated.